# WPF - DataTemplate without a container, items as rows in a Grid?

Tags: .net, wpf, templates, xaml, grid

Is there an equivalent mechanism to the `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` that works with a `Grid`?  I have a collection of items and I'd like to present them as rows in a `Grid` so that I can assign `Grid.Column` to the individual elements inside the template (as opposed to rows in a list control).  Is this possible in WPF using standard controls?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, use an ItemsControl with the `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true"` attached property applied. Next, for your your ItemTemplate, you use a `<Grid>` just like you normally would except now when you add `ColumnDefinition`s you set the `SharedSizeGroup` attribute to a name that is unique for each column. So for example:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MyFirstColumn" />
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MySecondColumn" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding MyFirstProperty}"/ >
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MySecondProperty}"/ >
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

For more on IsSharedSizeScope and SharedSizeGroup, [check out this section of the SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope.aspx). It should be noted that RowDefinitions also have a SharedSizeGroup so that you could do horizontal layouts as well.

Comment: Yeah...that looks like the route I'm going.

Comment: very helpful. in the same situation (i needed to set `<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>`) i also wanted 2nd column to fill remaining space. It worked if i didn't set `SharedSizeGroup` for 2nd column:  `<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MyFirstColumn" />` `<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>`  `<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MyThirdColumn" />`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood your problem, but isn't it exactly what a [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.aspx) does ?

Comment: Thanks...didn't even know that existed

Comment: Actually, this is not at all what I'm looking for.  I don't want all the extra fancy "data grid" formatting.  I don't want column headers, the sorting functionality, the default padding and background, etc.  I want to repeat items in a collection laid out in a grid the way I would normally do it in an ItemsControl...nothing more than that.  Know of anything?

Comment: ok... just to make sure I understand : you want the items laid out horizontally instead of vertically ?

Comment: yes, like a grid, but without all the overhead and fluff of the GridView.  I actually decided on the same solution that Drew suggested.  Using a regular Grid, but using SharedSizeGroup to bind the column widths outside of the DataTemplate